# Why is it good save to save sessions in the database?

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter, session, security

I have seen that codeigniter have facility to save session values in database.
It says saving session in database is good security practice.

But I think saving session information in the database helps improve performance.
They save only a few elements of the session, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'ci_sessions' (
  session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  user_data text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

But if a site uses more session variables such as username, last log in time, etc, I can save them in database and use them in the program.

Do I have to add these columns to the same table?
I think saving session information in the database only helps reduce web servers' memory usage (RAM).
Can anybody explain in what sense does it improve security.

Comment: What are you comparing to? To a file based store or a cookie based store?

Comment: Redis is a good option

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It doesn't improve security in any way.

The most common and reasonable pattern to store sessions in database is when you have several frontend servers, so you need a shared session storage for them.

For downvoters: a file in filesystem isn't less secured than a record in database.

Comment: Oh, even 2 downvotes. Any comments on that action? I'm curious )

Comment: As Tim said, IP match can be a relevant security method.

Comment: I was refering to his very last sentence.

Comment: @Aurélien Grimpard: and how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Just read zerkms, i was refering to his last sentence "And can anybody explain what causes to improve security". As you can see i didn't answered, just commented. He wants to know how DB storage of session can improve security ... sounds relevant to me, no ?

Comment: @zerkms I didn't downvoted your answer and I do agree with your point with complex server setups. So how do you usually tackle session hijacking (without assuming all the HTTPS ONLY flags and other browser-specific stuff ?)

Comment: @Ayesh K: there are various techniques, depends on the requirements and your skills. One of the basic and good enough for most projects - is to keep useragent + IP in the session and compare it each request.

Comment: I dont know how you say exactly file system is more secure than database record but you bring a good point. thanks.

Comment: @kiriappa: I didn't say it's more secure either. Nothing of them is more or less secure, because "it depends"

Comment: but nobody says about performance? doesnt it causes to performance?

Comment: @kiriappa: "performance" term makes only sense in a particular case. If different 2 solutions solve the issue - you can and need to compare their performance (there may be a lot of criterias for that). If solutions are incomparable - then you just have no choice :-)

Comment: what I mean is, if 10000000 users are logged in to my site at once, then I need a big memory to handle their session. what if we save them in database? doesnt it cause to improve performance in that case?

Comment: @kiriappa: what do you mean when say "memory"? What kind of memory? In neither cases the session data is stored in RAM. "doesnt it cause to improve performance in that case" --- this question makes no sense. You cannot say if something would improve performance without *detailed investigation*. Performance optimization process are barely unified. So in each particular case you need to perform different optimizations. That is.

Comment: is it a good idea to hit database on every page hit that require a session?

Comment: `a file in filesystem isn't less secured than a record in database.` but this is what I  find at http://www.hackingwithphp.com/10/3/7/files-vs-databases : " If session data is stored in files, the files would need to be in a shared location somewhere - not ideal for performance or locking reasons."

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed how your quote is relevant to security? There is literally not even a single word about security in the piece you quoted.

Comment: @zerkms, if in a shared hosting environment, admins of other sites with the same hosting can play with the session files, right ? I am just trying to understand .

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed nope. I highly doubt you can find any hosting configured like that. Or please provide a particular example.

Comment: @zerkms Can we talk sir, I had some doubts regarding sessions

Comment: @SurajJain ask a question and post a link to it here

Comment: @zerkms  Sir, i no longer ask questions here, they only get down voted

Answer (score 29):

The idea is that sessions can't be hijacked.

A session ID is stored in a cookie. If a hacker can steal that ID, he can pretend to be someone else, because a session is identified by... it's ID.

By saving a user's session ID, IP and agent server-side (your database for example) you can compare the data saved in the database with the client. If a hacker steals someone's session ID, the hacker just might not have a matching IP and/or user-agent, making the users not match which allows you to show or hide certain content.

You have to compare the data manually though.

Comment: How is it related to the question? Regardless of where you store the sessions - you still need to persist SID somewhere on the client.

Comment: We stre the IP/ UserAgent String in the session database row so at least we can prevent someone hijacking same session from a different IP or software.

Comment: @Ayesh K: session storage has **nothing** to do with hijacking.

Comment: A malicious user can fake both SESSID and IP address, this check doesn't make your application safer.

Comment: If you can save IP and user-agent into database you can also save this data into that session too!

Answer (score 9):

A common security faux-pas with file-based sessions is to store them in `/tmp` or another shared directory where the data may be accessible to 3rd parties; especially on shared hosts this can be a problem. This can be prevented with proper file permissions though.

Storing them in a database means you have all the access restrictions of the database in place, though that also means you need to configure them correctly and set up the physical storage of the database securely.

It improves performance insofar as the database server has more layers to improve performance through caching and in-memory storage, whereas file based sessions always incur a disk access. Concurrent access can be improved since you can choose other concurrency mechanisms than file locking. If your database server is already busy with regular database work though, additionally throwing session handling at it may or may not be a good idea.

Comment: "Concurrent access is also better since no file-locking is necessary." --- you still need to maintain row locks

Comment: @zerkms But you can *read* from the database while someone else is writing, file based sessions lock each other out entirely.

Comment: reading when someone else is writing will cause the session data loss. (in case if one thread has written after you've read the data, you'll owerwrite it with obsolete data)

Comment: @zerkms OK, true. There are of course many ways to deal with this, as in regular database work, and it depends on what you need to do. If you seldom write to the session but need to read it on every page load, optimistic locking is probably a real advantage over file-based sessions.

Comment: well, it's a bit offtopic indeed, but I see the only real reason: to have a shared storage.

Comment: does it keep session value in file system or ram(memory)?

Comment: @kiriappa Databases you mean? It depends on your database. Typically all data in a database is ultimately written to disk, but recently used data is also typically stored in memory for faster access.

Answer (score 4):

This is to answer: can I save them in the database and utilize them in the program?

Yes, you can save them in the database,but there is no need to create a separate column for that. It goes into the userdata column.

You can set the username with
`$this->session->set_userdata('sessionname',session value);`

You can retrieve it with
`$var=$this->session->userdata('sessionname');`

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention if you use PHP or MYSQL, but saving your session in a database does not give you better performance, in fact quite the opposite.

The default file based session in PHP is much faster than retrieving session values from the database, however you won't really notice the difference until you're processing hundreds of queries per second.

Answer (score 2):

- The application needs to be able to run on multiple servers without
  server affinity (methods that direct requests from the same client to
  the same server). An easy way to make sure that sessions continue to
  work properly is to store sessions in a central database that is
  common to all servers.
- The application needs to be able to run on a shared host, where there
  are significant security concerns associated with storing session
  data in the filesystem.
- The performance needs of the application are very demanding and
  require a more sophisticated storage solution for session data. There
  are many existing ideas and methodologies that address database
  performance issues, and these can be used when sessions are stored in
  a database.

**Reference**

Chris, S (2004, 14 Dec). *Storing Sessions in a Database.* Chris Shiflett Blog. https://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database