# Authenticating PHP Session

Tags: php, sql, session

I have this function that checks if a user logs in correctly (that all works). The success response sends this

```
// Success array, send back requested information for settings
$response = array(
    'status' => '1',
    'response' => array(
        'uid' => $data->id,
        'email' => $data->email,
        'username' => $data->username,
        'key' => $this->hash($data->id . $data->username . $data->email)
    )
);
```

The `$response['response']` contains all the session variables that will be set. An example of the `key` being set would look like this

```
// Returns this : 5da099bda1be066384e8574f7de198dcef014ce28e99694239d2237b7ec854aa
print $this->registry->user->hash('1','test','test@test.com');
```

Now would it be safe to set that key in a session variable and run a check like this (which I currently do):

```
public function authenticate_session() {
        if (isset($_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION)) {
            if ($_SESSION['key'] !== $this->hash($_SESSION['uid'] . $_SESSION['username'] . $_SESSION['email'])) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Or should I store the key in a database and run a cross check against said database to check that the session is valid?

And with that I'd run a check in the top of a file:

```
<?php 
    if(!$this->registry->user->authenticate_session()) {
        $this->registry->user->end_session();
        die(header("Location: /user/login));
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to make sure you `exit;` after redirecting - otherwise, your script will keep executing.

Comment: @SamDufel sorry I forgot to add full, i just `die()` the header

Comment: I think your question is about better way not how to... like, this link would be useful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911210/why-is-it-good-save-session-in-database and http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/