# Merge login/signup for multiple sites on same server

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple PHP/MySQL-based sites hosted on the same dedicated server (Apache). As things stand now, users have to sign-up/log-in separately for each site. Now, I would like to allow the merging of user accounts from all sites into 1. There are two things I need to do, for one I have a solution and for the other I don't.

1) When user signs up on one site, his account should be created on all sites. This is fairly easy to accomplish by creating several database connections on each site's sign-up page and creating entries in each site's database.

2) When user logs into one site, he should be logged into all sites. This I don't know how to do, since the logins are session-based. Either a new login session on one site has to (somehow) be created on all sites or I need to alter the login script to work in some other way.

I know there are groups of sites that have a similar feature (such as the Stack Overflow family) so I hope someone can tell me how to do this.

Comment: Instead of using separate user database tables for each site, is it possible to use a central table? That will greatly simplify the signup process, anyway. The tables ought to have pretty similar structure, no?

Comment: The table are very similar and could be joined into one, but how do I resolve the problem of transferring login sessions between sites?

Comment: It is possible to store sessions in the database
here is a link of a similar question [stack overflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911210/why-is-it-good-save-session-in-database)!

Comment: You could use database-based sessions in PHP, or establish a central domain as the authenticator, and treat that like a service/API that the other site use. This could be a new domain, or you could just use one of the existing sites that all the other sites treat as the master.

Comment: So, instead of posting the login form to whatever site they are on, the post goes to `centrallogin.somedomain.com`, which establishes the session/cookies. A class can wrap a check to that domain in a curl request, their first visit to one of your "family" sites will check their session status with a curl request, and if logged in, cache it as a cookie/session variable.

Comment: @Chris Sorry to bring this up again two months later - do you know how I could make this work with cookies? I'd like to keep the user logged into all sites for 2 weeks, presumably by setting a cookie on the central site, but can I check that with a curl request?

Comment: @jovan Yes, you can check a cookie with a curl request. The manual has all the details.

Comment: @Chris I've been looking but can't find that information. Can you link me to a resource for this specific problem? Since the cookie is connected to the user-agent, how does the site that we target with the curl request even know what browser the visitor is using? Or anything about the visitor for that matter?

Comment: Did you Google "php curl cookies"? I could link you to the documentation page on php.net, but I don't want to seem snarky. It's just that there are thousands of pages I could link to, and linking to Google results also seems snarky. Heck, this comment seems snarky. Not my intention -- the information is very, very, very widespread and easy to get to, I wouldn't know which link to start with.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish something like this, you could allow logins via all of the popular social media sites. Examples being Facebook, Google, Twitter, OpenID.

If you are interested in how exactly the SO family achieves this, read this blog article:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/

Comment: Well, that's a possibility, but I already have about 30000 users (across all sites) and they all signed up using their email/password, so this wouldn't really work for them at this point.

Comment: Read this article to explain the process of implementing a global login system over multiple domains using javascript, localstorage and cookies - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274