# Why we need to store session in database codeigniter 3.0?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have read the codeigniter document about session. but i still don't understand why they implement accessing session in database?

[Session Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session)

Any comments would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big deal with it. It means there is **no any Security Reason** for it

Main purpose of this is **store user logins**, and **managing** those.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Ex :`timestamp` will gather the user logging time. So you can get detail about how many time user log in to site

[Codeigniter Store Session](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#database-driver)
[why is it good save session in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911210/why-is-it-good-save-session-in-database)

Comment: thanx for your help (y)

Answer (score 0):

On codeigniter 3 you do not need to store sessions in database you can do it with out or use files

config.php  starting from line 358

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 1440;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/somefolder';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```