# How to sharing sessions (PHP/MySQL) across multiple DNS domain/subdomains diff Server

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, session, dns

I need to maintain PHP sessions across multiple subdomain or domains on the same server. I am going to be integrating my sites with a Register/Payment gateway, etc.., So i will need to use MySQL based sessions.

Ex. subdomain to sharing in between ..,

[test.com](http://test.com)

[register.test.com](http://register.test.com)

[myaccount.test.com](http://myaccount.test.com)

Are there any other options? Pros/Cons?

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: save the sessions in a DB

Comment: @volkinc: Any method available .. model  script..?

Comment: the approach is, you run common db that store sessions with the fields like id, site, sessionid, date So all requests will path through this table so don't forget to   clean it up. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911210/why-is-it-good-save-session-in-database and Google for examples